# MouseEnter event is not firing intermittently while hovering on states in VML map

Tags: mouseenter, vml

I have a VML map like this:

(A sample of the structure used)

```
<div class="map" jQuery1351170963063="74">
<div class="usmap" jQuery1351170963063="75">
<group class="g vg" style="visibility: visible;" jQuery1351170258860="79" height="256px" width="434px" coordsize="21600,21600">
<shape class="vmap" id="Maryland_md" jQuery1351170258860="105"/>
<shape class="vmap" id="Delaware_de" jQuery1351170258860="104"/>
<shape class="vmap" id="Alaska_ak" jQuery1351170258860="94">
</group>
</div>
</div>
```

On IE7 & IE8, sometimes the mouseenter event is not firing while hovering over the shape nodes.

JS code:

```
var $canvas = $(".usmap", $this);
var $canvasParent = $canvas.parent();
var mouseenterEvent = "mouseenter";
var mouseleaveEvent = "mouseleave";

$(".g", $canvas).delegate(element, mouseenterEvent + " " + mouseleaveEvent, onMouseEnterVMLShape)
                .add($canvas).add($keys).add($canvasParent).mouseleave(onMouseLeaveVMLShape);
```